# How do I test helper methods using Shoulda and set the params and request values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, shoulda

I'm using rails 2.2.2 and wondering how can I set the params values to test my helper methods.

I found some examples to let you run tests with helper methods but it doesn't work for me when I use the request or params value directly in the method.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductHelperTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include ProductHelper

  context 'ProductHelper' do
    should 'build the link' do
      assert_equal '', build_link
    end
  end
end
```

When using the request or params value I'll get an error that the local variable or method is undefined. How would I go about setting the value?

Error from shoulda when using the request value and it will be the same messages when using the params value.

```
1) Error:
test: ProductHelper should build the link. (ProductHelperTest):
NameError: undefined local variable or method `request` for #<ProductHelperTest:0x33ace6c>
  /vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_process.rb:471:in `method_missing`
  /app/helpers/products_helper.rb:14:in `build_link`
  ./test/unit/product_helper_test.rb:10:in `__bind_1251902384_440357`
  /vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.0.5/lib/shoulda/context.rb:254:in `call`
  /vendor/gems/thoughtbot-shoulda-2.0.5/lib/shoulda/context.rb:254:in `test: ProductHelper should build the link. `
  /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:94:in `__send__`
  /vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:94:in `run`
```

Comment: Can't you pass in the parameters from the view?

Comment: I'm trying to test existing code and they do not pass the values from the view and uses them directly. Most likely to reduce the number of parameters for the view functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have to mock out calls to `request` and `params` using `mocha` or by defining mock objects in your test:

```
# Assuming ProductHelper implementation
module ProductHelper
  def build_link
    "#{request.path}?#{params[:id]}"
  end
end

class ProductHelperTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include ProductHelper

  # mock by defining a method
  def params
    { :controller => "test", :id => "23" }
  end

  # mock request.path using `mocha` # => "my_url"
  def request
    mock(:path => "my_url")
  end

  context 'ProductHelper' do
    should 'build the link' do
      assert_equal 'my_url?23', build_link
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, this solution works perfectly. One change I made to it for the params and request functions were to return @request and @params so that I can redefine what should be returned in the context setups because the functions can only be redefined once per class.

Comment: Vizjerai - Do you have an example of this? I tried...


    @params = {};
    def params;
      @params;
    end;


But keep receiving nil.[] errors.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:
`controller.params = {:filter => {:user_id => 1}`

Here is an example:

```
require 'test_helper'

class BookmarksHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def test_some_helper_method
    controller.params = {:filter => {:user_id => 1}
    #... Rest of your test
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, if you are using Rails 2.3.x or anything which uses ActionView::TestCase - then all you really need to do is just have a private params method defined in your test.

e.g

```
require 'test_helper'

class BookmarksHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  context "with an applied filter of my bookmarks" do
    setup do
      expects(:applied_filters).returns({:my_bookmarks => true})
    end

    should "not be able to see it when other filters are called using my_bookmarks_filter" do
      assert_equal other_filters(:my_bookmarks), {}
    end
  end

  private

    def params
      {}
    end

end
```

You could even do one better by defining params as a method inside of ActionView::TestCase